# Todd-Coxeter Algorithm

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Use the Todd-Coxeter Algorithm to analyse the group generated by two elements x,y, with the following relations determine the order of the group and identify the group if you can.

$$x^3=y^3=1, xyx = yxy$$

Given function is,
$xyx = yxy$
Multiply $x^2$ to both sides we get, $x^3yx = x^2yxy$

Here we know that $x^3 = 1$ so,
$yx = yxyx^2$

on applying Right cancellation law $y = yxyx$

On applying Left cancellation Law $xyx = 1$

Similarly

$yxy = 1$

so, $xyx = yxy = 1$

Hence the order of the Group is 1 and the Types of Group is Cyclic.

Comment: I'm with you until Here we know $x^3 = 1$ so,...I get $ yx = x^2 y x y $

Comment: why commutative?

Comment: Meanwhile, if you experiment by adding the extra relation $x=y,$ you get the cyclic group of order three. So you have messed up in any case.

Comment: The question says use the Todd-Coxeter algorithm, which you have not attempted to do. I would do it over the subgroup $\langle x \rangle$. Expect 8 cosets!

Comment: @WillJagy I did the manipulations correctly now and found $x^2y^2x^2yxy=1$

Comment: Well, good. You really ought to look up the Todd-Coxeter algorithm in your book and do what @DerekHolt  suggests.

Answer (score 2):

**Note that I did what you were looking for in light of Derek's neat hint**

[image]

You see that $[G:\langle y\rangle]=8$ so the possibilities for $|G|$ could be $24$.